# accessing spreadsheet data from standalone app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've two spreadsheets in my Drive (SS1 and SS2)
I'd like to create a standalone app that read values from cells A1 to A10 of SS1 Sheet1 and paste theme into cells B1 to B10 of SS2 Sheet1.

How can I do this? How can I retrive data using a standalone app?

I've seen SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID') but, SS1 will be updated multiple times in the future (reuploaded and overwrited), it will maintain its name but not the ID, right?

Comment: A "standalone app" generally means entirely 3rd party code, e.g. something written outside of Google Apps Script. These applications must use the Sheets REST API, while an unbound/standalone Google Apps Script project can use the simplified `SpreadsheetApp` class.

Answer (score 1):

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID')
```

You got it backwards. It will maintain it's ID. But the name maybe changed. Drive also allows multiple uploads of the same name. So,ID is the only unique thing to separate a file from another.